# Do it yourself dependency injection with Typescript

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript

I tinkered with some dependency injection frameworks for Typescript but didn't like the magic & complexity they add. Thus I decided to give DIY DI a try.

The original document has examples for Java and I'm curious if I:

- got the concepts right (IOC, Demeter, ...)
- implemented it properly in Typescript

I'd be very thankful if someone who's experienced with Typescript or DIY DI could check my code and tell me if I, in general, got the concepts, point out some mistakes & provide me with additional information on how to improve.

- The document is here: http://blacksheep.parry.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/DIY-DI.pdf
- My implementation is here: https://github.com/mdix/diy-di-typescript

And another question popped up: How to deal with Interfaces? They can't be passed in via constructor, as they're needed when defining the class (`implements MyInterface`).

**Thank y'all for your help.**

Comment: Question might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com, but + 1 for "I tinkered with some dependency injection frameworks for Typescript but didn't like the magic & complexity they add. Thus I decided to give DIY DI a try."  I don't like DI frameworks either :)

Comment: @jrahhali Thanks! Did not know about codereview.stackexchange.com. Will try it there but also keep the question active here, just in case...

Comment: @jrahhali please take a minute to read [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788); Code Review **requires** the code to be reviewed, embedded in the post, not as a link to a github repository.

Comment: @Mat'sMug But that's no big deal. I can include the code. Thanks for the hint!